# PHP - exit or die() in AJAX requests?

Tags: php, ajax, json

What's the best practice here? Using die() or exit()? What's the difference between the two?

```
if($_GET['do_thing']):
  echo 'bla bla';
  exit(); // or die(), or something else?
endif;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`die('bla bla');`, `echo 'bla bla';exit();` and `exit('bla bla');` do the same thing. Personally, I use `die` only for debugging code, and an empty `exit` for regular termination - as in your case. However, `die` and `exit` are synonyms, so it does not matter which one you use.

Answer (score 3):

I use die() when making mysql queries to log the errors, I use exit to bail out of loops.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer die, but for no particular reason. PHP Docs say that exit is the real language construct (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) and [die is simply an alias](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php), but both work.
It just depends on your coding style and choice of grammar!